# iOS - Schedule http request

Tags: ios, nstimer, background-task

I am building a travel app which gives complete information about all transportation systems in my city. There is a requirement to notify the user when there is any change in time table of public transport/delay/any incident. To get that information, app has to hit the server at a specified time, say 9am everyday, and if anything is reported, that has to be notified to the user using local notification.

I am aware that this is not a proper design and there are many limitations with respect to Application states to fire the event. But still can iOS app manage such situation(which should work even when app is in background, suspended, inactive, terminated), as I am not getting any support from backend team?

Comment: No and yes, you can not really schedule any task. You can aks iOS to allow you app to a background refresh. But if the user does not allow background running of apps this will not be called. Also the background refresh will be called with an interval, set by iOS. 
Beste option, I know not possible, but a push notification will work. Even if the push notification is only used to tell the app to update it self.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if your backend team is not giving you any support then you are out of luck. Silent push is the only way to do this as per your requirement (exact time every day even if terminated). You could try the background update method, as apparently iOS learns when you're most likely to use a particular app and will schedule the update accordingly.